# Logging Application Block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

What will happen if I disable tracing in Logging Application Block

E.g.

```
<loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="false" defaultCategory="" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
<listeners>
.....
```

I have only one Trace and Trace Listener.

Comment: Disable it and see what happens! (In other words: "Don't ask me, ask the system!")

Answer (score 1):

The tracingEnabled attribute specifies whether activity tracing (using the Tracer class) is enabled.  It is not related to TraceListeners.